# Display Table & Display Table-Cell Not Working

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, css-tables

I am trying to auto align my navigation bar so that the logo and links are always aligned vertically. I added a "Display:Table;" to my main header and Sublime 2 whites out "Table" which means it's not latching on. It also whites out "Table-Cell" in my logo and links declarations. Needless-to-say, my code doesn't work.

Does anyone know why?

Here's the code:

```
<div class="header">
    <img id="GovDefendersLogo" src="images/GovDefendersLogo.png">
    <ol>
        <a href="mailto:govdefenders@dlt.com"><li class="links">Contact Us</li></a>
        <a href="blog"><li class="links">Blog</li></a>
        <a href="partners/index.html"><li class="links">Partners</li></a>
        <a href= "technology/index.html"><li class="links">Technology</li></a>
        <a href="index.html"><li class="links">Home</li></a>
    </ol>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.header {
    height: 77px;
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
    box-shadow: 0 0 16px 0 rgba(50,50,50,0.3);
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

#GovDefendersLogo {
    float: left;
}

ol {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: black;
}

.links {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
    list-style: none;
}

#GovDefendersLogo,
    .links {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: you `a`  tags should be inside the `li`tags of your `ol`.

Comment: [validate, validate, validate](http://validator.w3.org).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ol {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: black;
    display:table-row; /*added line*/
}
```

Move the anchor tags inside the `li` tags.

Do this if needed:

```
.links{
    float:none;
}
```

Comment: The table appears to be working, however, they aren't aligning vertically (through the middle) and now there's weird spacing between my links. Some of the links are close to each other and some are far away.

Any additional thoughts? This is my first time using CSS tables so I apologize for the questions.

Sublime still whites out table, table-row, and table-cell.

Comment: Can you check if this is what u want [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/n93ct/1/)

Comment: Almost. But the logo and links would be aligned vertically aligned central within the parent box. The demo had them aligned to the top.

Comment: That is because there is no space in the fiddle. Try enlarging the results area.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes from what James had done here ([**jSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/n93ct/1/))

To get the menu and logo to vertically aligned, here's what I've changed:

Remove clear:both from .header

```
.header {
    height: 77px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
    box-shadow: 0 0 16px 0 rgba(50,50,50,0.3);
    width: 100%;
}
```

Removed float:left from your logo with float:none:

```
#GovDefendersLogo {
    float: none;
}
```

Removed float:left and added line-height:77px; from  tag:

```
ol {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: black;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height: 77px;
}
```

**See updated code**

Check out the updated code in its entirety here **http://jsfiddle.net/wLhz3/**

Answer (score 0):

Mantaining the original code and writing less code to achieve what op's asking, the answer is:

```
ol {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: black;
  display: table-cell; // Add this
  vertical-align: middle; // Add this
}
```